# How important is periodization in force training?

Tags: workout-routines, workout, periodization

How important is a periodization planning in a weight, force training? I mean the exercises you do in a gym besides the cardios.

I'm not a professional in the field, but I started to study periodization of training. I understand that it's a methodology created for high level athletes, but there are authors that adapted it to force training and I don't see anybody using it in gyms.

So the benefits of a periodization are smaller for non athletes? What's the difference between doing the same exercises with no recuperation microcycles over 2 months or doing a periodization where I follow weeks less intense and others more intense?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason you haven't seen it, is because it might be hard to notice other people's periodization. But it's pretty widely used, and the most common periodization we have is what we call a "deload".

After a few months of training heavy, it's inevitable that you'll hit a plateau in terms of progress, because let's face it, we can't have linear progression forever. If we did, we'd all be benching tons.

The deload is a period where we really let the body recuperate in terms of resting. We might still train in this period, but it's going to be light weights, and not really fatiguing yourself all that much. The idea is to just give the muscles, as well as the central nervous system, some time off. A vacation if you will.

We often experience a surge of power just after the deload, feeling stronger than ever. This pretty much lets us know that a deload was a good idea, and we can get back to the usual routine again.

I wouldn't say the benefits are smaller for non-athletes. Of course, if you compete, you have a bit more to gain from a well-time deload, but a non-athlete experiences the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Important? Not particularly, but it can be a very useful tool.

It is commonly used in some capacity in basically any programme designed to get you stronger once you are past the first few years of training. You can try to incorporate it into your training and see how you like it.

> What's the difference between doing the same exercises with no recuperation microcycles over 2 months or doing a periodization where I follow weeks less intense and others more intense?

It's just a different method. You focus on certain characteristics of your training at a time and really give them your all. So instead of trying to be a jack of all trades constantly; you instead become a master of one type of training at a time.

Does it make you stronger faster? Some claim so. Depends on your goals and training advancement.

Answer (score 0):

**Let's make this clear**

Periodization is a way to conceptualize training developed by russian coaches that helped to **manipulate the time** with which an athlete reacted to training.

Even for a beginner periodization is actually more useful than going blind.

The issue between advanced athletes and beginners is about **two majour points**:

*1*- **Minimum load necessary**: the minimum load that an athlete requires to produce a supercompensation and thus results.

*2*- **Heterogeneity of skills targeted**: dividing the workload on multiple target will diminish the amount of workload each one is going to get.

If for beginners is good to target multiple skills at the same time ( because each one of them will get the right amount of load ), its not the same for an advanced athlete. And when I say "skill" I'm referring either to a conditional capacity like anaerobic power or a coordinative skill like trowing a hammer.

At this purpose in the 80s, Vladimir Issurin came up with the Block Periodization: a multipeak performance concept of periodization that helped to reduce the *hours*/*year* ratio of training and eventually improve performance. Right now is a concept widely adopted from most of the top level coaches.

Anyway what you're asking is simpler: yes, you will actually benefit of periodizing your training regimen EVEN if you're a novice.

The timing is based mostly on how well you know the athlete and his/her body ( or yours, in the case you wanna apply this to yourself ) and the reaction it has.

The reduction of volume in strenght training is actually crucial, because at the same time intensity goes up if its a realization microcycle and in that time you notice most of your progress.